# How connect faster in XMPP Video Calls?

Tags: voip, xmpp

It takes 10 to 30 seconds to establish a connection, when I call another user for a video call via XMPP. I tried different devices. clients and servers.

As soon as the connection is settled, I see no limitations in the video conference and the video streams at full resolution.

My last test was with GrapheneOS on a Pixel 6a and Conversation as client both in the same Wireless LAN and the Users had accounts on the same server.

How can I find out the cause for the long delay?
How can I make it faster?

Comment: Have you checked if direct communication between Wifi clients is allowed? Some routers, especially in open Wifis or guest networks block direct client-to-client traffic. For getting more details I would recommend to make a Pcap/Wireshark capture of a traffic of the clients. If the delay is caused by some network timeouts then you may see that in the network capture.

Comment: @Robert yes, the connection is perfect. I also tried it with different devices and in different networks. It seems to me that the first handshake takes very long.